# unique_ptr with reinterpret_cast, will the structure get freed correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, reinterpret-cast

Will my dynamically allocated structure get freed properly by the unique_ptr ?

```
unique_ptr<sockaddr> p;

switch (type) {
    case AF_INET:
        p.reset( reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(new sockaddr_in) );
        break;
    case AF_INET6:
        p.reset( reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(new sockaddr_in6) );
        break;
    case AF_UNIX:
        p.reset( reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(new sockaddr_un) );
        break;
    default:
        throw domain_error("Invalid domain");
}
```

Do you have better alternatives ? Is this a good coding style? Is it better to have 3 separate unique_ptr for each structure instead of only 1 ?

Comment: Hard to say. What are `sockaddr_FOO`? Are they subclasses of `sockaddr`? Then as long as they have a virtual destructor, C++ will just Do The Right Thing without you having to do ugly casts to base. But if they're not - which, assuming they are Linux/POSIX things, they won't be - then you have UB by simply giving them to somewhere that expects a `sockaddr *`. Even if `sockaddr_FOO` have a `sockaddr` as first member, making the cast 'valid', you'll still have UB when destroying them.

Comment: For unrelated object types where only one can be present at any one time, see `std::variant` or if required some C++11 backport thereof.

Comment: Since this looks as if the unique_ptr  is around for a while, and you just change values "under the hood", and you are using plain old C data types: Allocate a union and just assign one of the members according to the `type`. Saves a lot of cycles needed for dynamic memory handling at the cost of a few spare bytes in the union. This looks like a textbook example for why unions exist.

Answer (score 0):

Unique ptr deletes its argument.  Deleting things as the type they where not allocated as only avoids UB in narrow circumstances.

I'd be conservative and do this

```
template<class T, class U>
auto cleanup_as=[](U* u){ delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(u);};

template<class T>
using my_up=std:unique_ptr<T,void(*)(T*)>;

template<class T, class U>
my_up<T> wrap_up_as(U*pu){
  return my_up<T>(pu, cleanup_as<U,T>);
}
```

then your code becomes

```
my_up<sockaddr> p;

switch (type) {
  case AF_INET:
    p = wrap_up_as<sockaddr>( new sockaddr_in );
    break;
```

etc.

Here the extra function pointer destroyer in the unique ptr remembers how the structure was allocated, and at destruction cleans it up properly.  Then some helper glue to make it easy to use.